# Two factor authentication not sending code to email when UserName is not an email address

Tags: c#, owin, asp.net-identity-2

I am using Two Factor Authentication using Owin identity 2.0 by email, I am facing problem in sending email as my ApplicationUser model has UserName and Email properties. If UserName is not an email address then code is not sending to email address but if UserName is an email address then its working fine.
Any possible solution will be appreciated.

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        try
        {
            if (await SignInManager.SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(model.SelectedProvider))
            {
                Logger.Info("Email sent to " + model.UserName);
                return new { Sent = true };
            }
            Logger.Info("Email not sent to " + model.UserName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { Logger.Error(e.Message); }
        return new { Sent = false };
```

Answer (score 1):

You said, that you have an UserName property and an Email property. Why aren't you just using the Email address as reciever instead of the UserName?

Comment: Its requirement, users can login with email or username.